# double.ToString("format") for netMF - Argument Exception

Tags: c#, formatting, tostring, .net-micro-framework

I am having trouble getting the format to work correctly with double.ToString() in **netMF4.3**. And Also `int.ToString("format")`

I am looking to to format a double with 3 leading zeros and no decimal places. For that matter any amount of leading zeros. Here's my code.

```
double myDouble = 23.2;
string myString = myDouble.ToString("000"); // I've tried other formats
// Expected Result : "023"
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll

I've read through the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee436730.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.102).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh401614.aspx) but I get a System.ArgumentException when I try any formatting strings.

This code works in the emulator, but it does not seem to work when deployed on an actual device.

Comment: The string formatting in the Micro Framework is limited. It only allows you to select between three general settings and select the number of decimal places. In my emulator, I do hit that System.ArgumentException with your code. You can return no decimal places with "F00" but you will have to add the leading zeros yourself.